# Java - Set width/height of JLabel

Tags: java, applet, jlabel

I am adding an image into a JLabel and trying to set the width and height... but it's not working... help?

as you can see here... the tiles are not 32 by 32...

[image]

code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LayoutExample extends JApplet {

    Label msgL = new Label("Messages");
    Label statusL = new Label("Status");
    Label inventoryTitleL = new Label("Your Inventory");
    Label idL = new Label("Name, Stats");
    Label messageInL = new Label("read message here");
    Label messageOutL = new Label("type message here");
    JLabel label2;
    JPanel topP;
    JPanel topRightP;
    JPanel gameGridP;
    JPanel inventoryP;
    JPanel inventoryTitleP;
    JPanel inventoryGridP;
    JPanel idP;
    JPanel messageInP;
    JPanel messageOutP;
    JButton slot;
    TextArea chat;
    TextField msg;

    /** Game variables **/
    Image[] tiles;
    Image[] weapon;
    Image player; // player image
    int x, y, px, py, tx, ty; // x tile - y tile // player x - player y // tile x - tile y
    boolean left, right, down, up, canMove, respawn;
    boolean drawFlail, drawBattleaxe;
    public static int[][] board;
    final int NUM_TILES = 522;
    final int NUM_WEAPS = 2;
    boolean[] weaponPicked;
    Label lx, ly; // to see where we are!
    int r1, r2, u1,u2,l1,l2,d1,d2, spawnX, spawnY;
    int rightSide = 480;
    int downSide = 320;
    int mapX = 15;
    int mapY = 10;
    String txtLastFX, txtLastFY;
    boolean boolRC, boolLC, boolUC, boolDC;
    int leftMap, upMap, rightMap, downMap, currentMap, map;
    public static TextArea c = new TextArea();
    public static TextArea stats = new TextArea();
    public static String newline;
    public static java.awt.List list;

    public static Font TimesR = new Font("MonoSpaced", Font.BOLD, 15);
    public static ArrayList<String> arr;
    public static tileGen anItem;
    public static boolean firstpush = false;
    String name, desc, typeOf, attackAdd, defenseAdd, canSell, canEat,earnedCoins,canEquip;
    public static int blkStr;


    int lastX, lastY, row, col;
    Label lbl1, lbl2, p1, p2, lblRC;

        String username;
    int attack, defense, gold, level, exp;

    public void init() {

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(840,520));

        tiles = new Image[522];
        for(int i = 0;i < 522;i++) {
        tiles[i] = getImage(getClass().getResource(String.format("line_tile/t%d.png", i)));
        }

board = loadBoard(1);

        GridLayout frameGL = new GridLayout(3,2);

        frameGL.setVgap(0);
        frameGL.setHgap(0);

        //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        setLayout(frameGL);


        topP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        //topP.setBounds(0,0,640,520);
        topP.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(840,520));
        topP.setSize(new Dimension(840,520));
        GridLayout gameGridGL = new GridLayout(15,10);
        gameGridGL.setVgap(0);
        gameGridGL.setHgap(0);
        gameGridP = new JPanel(gameGridGL);

        gameGridP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,320));



        topP.add(gameGridP);

        topRightP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        inventoryP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        inventoryTitleP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        inventoryTitleP.setBounds(480,0,160,30);
        inventoryGridP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,4));
        //inventoryGridP.setBounds(480,0,160,128);
        //inventoryGridP.setHeight("160px");
        inventoryGridP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,128));
        idP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));

        messageInP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        messageOutP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        chat = new TextArea(10,50);
        msg = new TextField(50);


        inventoryTitleP.add(inventoryTitleL);
        inventoryP.add(inventoryTitleP);

        topP.add(inventoryGridP);
        inventoryP.add(inventoryTitleP);
        inventoryP.add(inventoryGridP);
        topRightP.add(inventoryP);

        for (int number = 1; number <= 20; number++) {
        inventoryGridP.add(slot = new JButton("Slot " + number));
        }

        idP.add(idL);
        topRightP.add(idP);
        topP.add(topRightP);

        add(topP);

        messageOutP.add(chat);
        messageOutP.setSize(640,20);
        //add(messageOutP);

        messageInP.add(msg);
        messageInP.setSize(150,640);
        //add(messageInP);

        player = getImage(getClass().getResource("me.gif")); // our player

    }

private static final HashSet<Integer> BLOCKED_TILES = new HashSet<Integer>();
static {

BLOCKED_TILES.add(118);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(67);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(190);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(40);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(135);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(520);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(25);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(91);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(394);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(1);
BLOCKED_TILES.add(121);
//add more tiles here
}


    public void stop() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {



        for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
        int index = board[row][col];
        Icon newTile = new ImageIcon(tiles[index]);
        label2 = new JLabel(newTile);



    //g.drawImage(tiles[index], 32 * col, 32 * row, this);
        gameGridP.add(label2);
        System.out.println(row + " " + col);
        }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
    paint(g);
    }

    public int[][] loadBoard(int map) {
        if (map == 1) {
     return new int[][] {
    { 118, 118, 118, 118, 34, 343, 67, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 118, 118, 118, 34, 343, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 40, 7, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 118, 34, 34, 34, 34, 135, 167, 167, 1, 167, 167, 167, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 118, 34, 343, 343, 343, 1, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 67, 34, 343, 343, 343, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 67, 34, 343, 394, 343, 1, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 67, 67, 34, 343, 343, 343, 1, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 343, 1, 1, 167, 167, 167, 167, 167, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 67, 121, 121, 67, 34, 343, 70, 1, 439, 25, 91, 25, 439, 1, 343, 343
     },
    { 118, 190, 190, 67, 34, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 34, 343, 343, 343, 343, 520
     },
    { 118, 190, 190, 67, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 520, 520, 520, 520, 520
     }
    };
     }else if (map == 4) {

      return new int[][] {

    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67, 343
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     }
    };

     }else if (map == 2) {

      return new int[][] {

    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67, 343
     },
    { 343, 67, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67, 67
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 67
     }
    };

     }else if (map == 3) {

      return new int[][] {

    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 124, 343
     },
    { 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 118, 118, 118, 343, 118, 343, 343, 118, 343, 124, 343
     },
    { 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 343, 343, 118, 343, 343, 118, 343, 124, 343
     },
    { 343, 118, 118, 118, 343, 118, 118, 343, 343, 118, 343, 343, 118, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 343, 343, 118, 343, 343, 118, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 118, 343, 118, 343, 118, 118, 118, 343, 118, 118, 343, 118, 118, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 121, 343, 121, 121, 343, 121, 121, 121, 343, 121, 121, 121, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 121, 343, 121, 343, 343, 121, 343, 121, 121, 121, 343, 121, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 121, 343, 343, 121, 343, 121, 343, 121, 343, 121, 343, 121, 343, 343, 124
     },
    { 343, 121, 343, 121, 121, 343, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 121, 124, 124, 124, 124
     }
    };
     }else if (map == 5) {

      return new int[][] {

    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 343
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 133, 133, 133, 343, 343, 343, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 167, 167, 133, 343, 343, 1, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 167, 167, 133, 343, 1, 343, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 167, 167, 133, 343, 1, 343, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 167, 167, 133, 343, 1, 1, 1, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 133, 133, 140, 133, 343, 343, 343, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 1, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 1, 1
     },
    { 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 343, 1, 1
     }
    };

     }

    return board;
    }


    public boolean blocked(int tx, int ty) {
    return BLOCKED_TILES.contains(board[ty][tx]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you can call `label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height))` to make something be forced at a size.  Not sure exactly what you're trying to do here - your SSCCE isn't all that [short](http://sscce.org/#short).

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with the posted code:

a) Don't use AWT components in a Swing Application. All components used should start with "J" (ie. JLabel, JTextArea, JTextField)

b) The code you have posted was copied from an old AWT Applet. Swing Applets are coded differently. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for a basic example. For example you should NEVER override the update() or paint() methods in a JApplet or JFrame or JDialog.

c) There is no need to set the size of a JLabel. The label will automatically be the size of the Icon added to it.

Clean up your code and then post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) if you still have problems. I'm not about to look through a hundred lines of code to figure out where you read the image and add it to a label.